# Converting string to array object using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I convert the following string using JavaScript to array:

```
from: var x = "{id:'2'},{name:'code,Barer'}";
to: var x1 = [{id:"2"},{name:"code,Barer"}];
```

Comment: Change the string so that it's valid JSON, then call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: That is not valid JSON as it requires double quotes and the properties' names to be quoted also. Also, you'd require to enclose that in `[]`s, such as: `var x = '[{"id":"2"},{"name":"code,Barer"}]';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that exact string to be an array object you can do this:

```
var x = "{id:'2'},{name:'code,Barer'}";
var newArray = eval("[" + x + "]");
```

Here are some the dangers of `eval`: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

How are you getting the variable `x`?  If you can get whatever it is to spit out valid JSON (using `JSON.stringify` or something similar) you can then parse it correctly into JS (although some implementations of JSON parsers do use eval).

Comment: +1 for mentioning `eval` with immediate warning on why not to use it

Comment: Thanks! it worked well. I'm getting my x variable through another function/method created by someone else. The function gets data from REST and renders it into somewhat of a JSON format I guess.

Comment: I fully recommend modifying that other function that is created by someone else so that you don't put yourself at risk with the `eval` :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `eval` for security reasons try this

```
var string = "{id:'2'},{name:'code,Barer'}",
    array = string.substr(1, string.length - 2)
                  .split("},{")
                  .map(function(item){
                         item = item.split(":");
                         var result = {}, 
                             name = item[0], 
                             value = item[1].replace(/'/g, "");
                         result[name] = value;
                         return result
                       });
```